# Radio button clears text boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two radio buttons: Click the first radio button and a three textboxes appear if they start entering information and then change their mind and select the second radio button it does not clear the text they have entered. So what I am trying to figure out is if there is a way make it clear the text from those textboxes when a new radio button (of the same group) is chosen. Any help is greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/k0paz2pj/

```
    <input 
      type="radio" 
      value="Yes" 
      name="lien" 
      id="lien" 
      onchange="showhideForm(this.value);"/><label for="lien">Lien</label>

   <input 
     type="radio" 
     value="None" 
     name="lien" 
     id="nolien" 
     onchange="showhideForm(this.value);"/><label for="nolien">No Lien</label>

    <div id="div1" style="display:none">
    <div class="clearfix">
           <p>
                <label for="lname">Lienholder Name:</label>
                  <input 
                    type="text" 
                    name="lienlname" 
                    id="lienlname">
                </p>
                <p>
                <label for="laddress">Lienholder Address:</label>
                  <input 
                    type="text" 
                    name="lienladdress"  
                    id="lienladdress">
                </p>
                <p>
                <label for="ldate">Date of Lien:</label>
                  <input 
                    type="text" 
                    name="lienldate" 
                    id="datepicker2">
                </p>
               </div>
    </div>
               <div id="div2" style="display:none">
    <!---You are not qualified to see this form.--->
    </div>

   <br>

    <script type="text/javascript">
function showhideForm(lien) {
    if (lien == "Yes") {
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'none';
    } 
   else if (lien == "None") {
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use this when another `radio` is checked:

```
$("#div1 .clearfix input:text").val("");
```

```js
function showhideForm(lien) {
    if (lien == "Yes") {
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'none';
    } 
   else if (lien == "None") {
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'none';
        $("#div1 .clearfix input:text").val("");//here use to clear inputs
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" value="Yes" name="lien" id="lien" onchange="showhideForm(this.value);"/><label for="lien">Lien</label>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" value="None" name="lien" id="nolien" onchange="showhideForm(this.value);"/><label for="nolien">No Lien</label>

<div id="div1" style="display:none">
<div class="clearfix">
       <p>
            <label for="lname">Lienholder Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="lienlname" id="lienlname">
            </p>
            <p>
            <label for="laddress">Lienholder Address:</label>
            <input type="text" name="lienladdress"  id="lienladdress">
            </p>
            <p>
            <label for="ldate">Date of Lien:</label>
            <input type="text" name="lienldate" id="datepicker2">
            </p>
           </div>
</div>
           <div id="div2" style="display:none">
<!---You are not qualified to see this form.--->
</div>
```

After (hate) comments (kidding) a js approach:

```js
function showhideForm(lien) {
  if (lien == "Yes") {
    document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'none';
  } else if (lien == "None") {
    document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'none';

    //js
    container = document.getElementById('div1');
    inputs = container.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
      inputs[index].value = "";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" value="Yes" name="lien" id="lien" onchange="showhideForm(this.value);" />
<label for="lien">Lien</label>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" value="None" name="lien" id="nolien" onchange="showhideForm(this.value);" />
<label for="nolien">No Lien</label>

<div id="div1" style="display:none">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <p>
      <label for="lname">Lienholder Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="lienlname" id="lienlname">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="laddress">Lienholder Address:</label>
      <input type="text" name="lienladdress" id="lienladdress">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="ldate">Date of Lien:</label>
      <input type="text" name="lienldate" id="datepicker2">
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">
  <!---You are not qualified to see this form.--->
</div>
```

Comment: You're giving OP a jQuery library to handle 1 javascript event? Seems excessive.

Comment: @AlexChar OP doesn't have a line of jQuery in their code. Could be a mistag, but I agree that it's overhead here. (Also note that jQuery is not loaded in the fiddle, but that's not a 100% clear determining factor)

Comment: create and an alternative js approach :)

Answer (score 6):

One approach, staying with the plain JavaScript from your question/JS Fiddle demo:

```
function showhideForm(lien) {
    if (lien == "Yes") {
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'none';
    } else if (lien == "None") {
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'none';

        // getting all the input elements within '#div1' (using a CSS selector):
        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#div1 input');

        // iterating over those elements, using Array.prototype.forEach,
        // and setting the value to '' (clearing them):
        [].forEach.call(inputs, function (input) {
            input.value = '';
        });

    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/k0paz2pj/6/).

A marginally more concise form of the above (or, if not more concise, with less repetition):

```
function showhideForm(lien) {    
    var isYes = lien.trim().toLowerCase() === 'yes',
        div1 = document.getElementById('div1'),
        div2 = document.getElementById('div2');

    div1.style.display = isYes ? 'block' : 'none';
    div2.style.display = isYes ? 'none' : 'block';

    if (!isYes) {
        [].forEach.call(div1.getElementsByTagName('input'), function (input) {
            input.value = '';
        });
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/k0paz2pj/9/).

And, finally, a version that moves away from the obtrusive JavaScript of in-line event-handling (`onclick`, `onchange`, etc):

```
function showhideForm() {
    // 'this' in the function is the radio-element to which
    // the function is bound as an event-handler: 
    var isYes = this.value.trim().toLowerCase() === 'yes',
        div1 = document.getElementById('div1'),
        div2 = document.getElementById('div2');

    div1.style.display = isYes ? 'block' : 'none';
    div2.style.display = isYes ? 'none' : 'block';

    if (!isYes) {
        [].forEach.call(div1.getElementsByTagName('input'), function (input) {
            input.value = '';
        });
    }
}

// finding the elements with the name of 'lien':
var lienRadios = document.getElementsByName('lien');

// iterating over those elements, using forEach (again):
[].forEach.call(lienRadios, function (lien) {
    // adding a listener for the 'change' event, when it
    // occurs the showhideForm function is called:
    lien.addEventListener('change', showhideForm);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/k0paz2pj/10/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementsByTagName).
- [`document.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementsByName).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).